# Project Reactor Schedulers on field level or chain level

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I saw that when schedulers are extracted to field or bean in Spring then Intellij suggest that is a blocking call in non-blocking scope. I know that but when I put Scheduler like below then Intellij treats this situation ok.

```
  return Mono.fromCallable(() -> /** BLOCKING CALL **/)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
```

Which version is better? Bean, field or chain level.. ?
Is Scheduler always singleton with the same name? If not then the scheduler at the chain level is a bad idea from an allocation perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in schedulers like `boundedElastic` are fine to be referenced as part of the chain, as they are singleton. Only if you use one of the methods with `new...` prefix like `newBoundedElastic` or the ones that start with `from...` like `fromExecutor`, then you should create them at fields level as they create new resources.